# Как получить информацию о авторе статьи из БД

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы: `pages`и `users`, в таблице `pages` есть поле `author_id`, которое связано с полем `id` в таблице `users` через `foreign key`. Как с помощью sql запроса получить информацию о авторе, зная `author_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` INNER JOIN `users` ON pages.author_id = users.id WHERE pages.id = ?"
```

На месте знака вопроса id страницы

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM pages JOIN users ON users.id = pages.author_id WHERE pages.author_id = [id]
```

PS Не совсем понятно что нужно выбрать. Данный запрос вернёт все записи с обеих таблиц по id

Comment: Я уже решил, но всё равно спасибо.